# Skip fragment of code C++ SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm writing a function in C++ with the SDL2 library, and I'm stuck with a small problem. The function deals with everything related to the graphics. I want to use it once to create the window, surface and so on ( *graphics(0,0)* ), and that everytime I use it after that it just updates the value of *x* and *y*, and updates the window surface. How can I do it?  I've tried everything I could think of, but in order to update the window surface I need to create the window again. Thanks in advance.

```
void graficos(int var1,int var2){
    int x = 0, y = 0; //declare the variables that will determine position of rectangle
    x += var1; y += var2; //declare the variables that will modify x & y
    //delcare graphics and load them
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
    SDL_Surface * surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Surface * texture = SDL_LoadBMP("texture.bmp");
    SDL_Rect rectangle = { x, y, 50, 50 };
    //render graphics
    SDL_BlitSurface(texture, NULL, surface, &rectangle);
    //update window
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    }
```

Comment: Can you make `SDL_Window` etc. be `static`? So long as you only ever have one of each, that would work. Alternatively, they could live outside of this function, and instead be passed in, where you'd check to see if they were null or not.

Comment: It works now! Thanks! You saved me so much effort. I'm quite new to programming :) Do you know any other way I could have done this?

Comment: So it sounds like these variables are essentially "Singletons" in that there should only ever be one of them. You can accomplish that in a number of ways, global variables being a sort of sledgehammer approach. Another way to go about it is to maybe not assume there's only ever one instance of `SDL_Window` etc., and make your functions actually receive a `SDL_Window*& window` etc. However, you only ever pass around a single instance. I'm sure other commenters will have ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**. You can break your function into two: `init` and `graficos` like this:

```
void init( SDL_Window * &window, SDL_Surface * &texture ) {
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        0
    );
    texture = SDL_LoadBMP("texture.bmp");
}

void graficos( SDL_Window * window, SDL_Surface * texture, int var1, int var2 ) {
// You can delete these lines and use var1 and var2 directly
    /*    int x = 0, y = 0; //declare the variables that will determine position of rectangle
    x += var1; y += var2; //declare the variables that will modify x & y
    */
    SDL_Surface * surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Rect rectangle = { var1, var2, 50, 50 };
    //render graphics
    SDL_BlitSurface(texture, NULL, surface, &rectangle);
    //update window
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
// somewhere in global place
SDL_Window * window;
SDL_Surface * texture;

// somewhere in initialization of programm
init( window, texture ); // call it only ones
...

graficos( window, texture, newX, newY ); // call it every time you need
```

**Second**. You can make `window` and `texture` as `static` like this:

```
void graficos(int var1,int var2){
    /*        int x = 0, y = 0; //declare the variables that will determine position of rectangle
    x += var1; y += var2; //declare the variables that will modify x & y
    */
    //delcare graphics and load them
// ---v---
    static SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);
// ---^---
    SDL_Surface * surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
// ---v---
    static SDL_Surface * texture = SDL_LoadBMP("texture.bmp");
// ---^---
    SDL_Rect rectangle = { x, y, 50, 50 };
    //render graphics
    SDL_BlitSurface(texture, NULL, surface, &rectangle);
    //update window
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
}
```

If there will be a voiting, then my voice would be for **first** :)

Comment: In the first case, what arguments do I write when calling them?

Comment: @gregalerna I have edited the answer with the example of usage